# Ajax event "select" not working for h:selectOneMenu in JSF 2.3 while it worked in 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3

I have developed project in JSF 2.2 using Mojarra, primeFaces 6.2 and Liberty server 18.0.0.4 version. Now am upgrading to JSF 2.3. I added jar file javax.faces.2.3.8.jar in my project class path. when I run the project I got below error,

```
 <f:ajax> Event:select is not supported
```

Below is the .xhtml code for h:selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="viewpanel" value="#{columnBean.columnView}" valueChangeListener="#{columnBean.dochange}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{columnBean.columnList}"/>
   <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{columnBean.getIdList()}" onstart="PF('wait').show();"/>
   <f:ajax event="select" listener="#{columnBean.getIdList()}" onstart="PF('wait').show();"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

JSF 2.2 its working fine without any issue. in JSF 2.3 am facing above issue.

Comment: And an `f:ajax`? Does that work?

Comment: No. It throw error **<f:ajax> 'select' is not supported event for HtmlSelectOneMenu**

Comment: Then it is not PF issue but a plain jsf one.

Comment: OK. Any Idea why  'select' event not supported in JSF 2.3.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onselect event removed for select components in JSF 2.3. refer below JSF 2.3 document 
  https://javaee.github.io/javaserverfaces-spec/downloads/JSF_2_3/Final/JSF_2.3.pdf